# 403 Forbbiden: Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/vi/client")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FHubClientController {

    private final FHubService fHubService;
    @GetMapping("/findAllUsersByRole")
    public List<User> findAllUsersByRole(@RequestParam("role") String role) {
        System.out.println("sdfasgf");

        return fHubService.findAllUsersByRole(role.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfiguration:

```
package com.org.fhub.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;

import static com.org.fhub.domain.user.Permission.*;
import static com.org.fhub.domain.user.UserRoleEnum.ADMIN;
import static com.org.fhub.domain.user.UserRoleEnum.STAFF;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                    authorize.requestMatchers(
                            "/api/v1/auth/**",
                            "/v2/api-docs",
                            "/v3/api-docs",
                            "/v3/api-docs/**",
                            "/swagger-resources",
                            "/swagger-resources/**",
                            "/configuration/ui",
                            "/configuration/security",
                            "/swagger-ui/**",
                            "/webjars/**",
                            "/swagger-ui.html"
                    ).permitAll();
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/api/v1/staff/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), STAFF.name());
                    authorize.requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/staff/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name(), STAFF_READ.name());
                    authorize.requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/staff/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name(), STAFF_CREATE.name());
                    authorize.requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/staff/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name(), STAFF_UPDATE.name());
                    authorize.requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/staff/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name(), STAFF_DELETE.name());
                    authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })

                /* .requestMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())

                 .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/admin/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name())
                 .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/admin/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name())
                 .requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/admin/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name())
                 .requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/admin/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name())*/

                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout((logout) -> logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout").addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()))
        ;

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My Filter:

```
package com.org.fhub.config;

import com.org.fhub.domain.token.TokenRepository;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().contains("/api/v1/auth")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if (authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                    .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
                    .orElse(false);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

My AplicationConfig:

```
package com.org.fhub.config;

import com.org.fhub.domain.user.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> repository.findUserByUserName(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

My jwtService:

```
package com.org.fhub.config;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${application.security.jwt.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;
    @Value("${application.security.jwt.expiration}")
    private long jwtExpiration;
    @Value("${application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration}")
    private long refreshExpiration;

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtExpiration);
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken(
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return buildToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails, refreshExpiration);
    }

    private String buildToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails,
            long expiration
    ) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

The token is valid and it says **authenticated=true**

the log produced:

```
2023-07-15T16:58:39.175+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@359e27d2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@277bc3a5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4ffa7041, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71fb8301, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@749d7c01, com.org.fhub.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter@7cc2c551, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@56b05bd7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3e4afd10, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@214fba74, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@485c84d7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5c4714ef, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7e1d8d41]] (1/1)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.177+01:00 DEBUG 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/v1/client/findAllUsersByRole?role=PLUS
2023-07-15T16:58:39.177+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.178+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.181+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.182+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.183+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:39.183+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-15T16:58:39.183+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:43.728+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.906+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.906+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.908+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.908+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.909+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User(id=64b2afc9b0ab605e709f61b6, username=kokoro, name=Brito, password=$2a$10$2PN0M.nH.tUa6sqXX/RaAOIS8kcH4FZUGEO9AzD6Dat/98gW7BF4S, notes=notas, role=PLUS, tokens=null), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_PLUS]]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.909+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.909+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.909+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.910+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@1e14ac53]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.923+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@1e14ac53] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@2918d923
2023-07-15T16:58:45.924+01:00 DEBUG 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/v1/client/findAllUsersByRole?role=PLUS
2023-07-15T16:58:45.937+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@359e27d2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@277bc3a5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4ffa7041, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71fb8301, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@749d7c01, com.org.fhub.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter@7cc2c551, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@56b05bd7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3e4afd10, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@214fba74, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@485c84d7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5c4714ef, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7e1d8d41]] (1/1)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 DEBUG 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?role=PLUS
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.940+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/api/v1/auth/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-07-15T16:58:45.941+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4a6fe6ad]]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.945+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4a6fe6ad]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@2918d923
2023-07-15T16:58:45.945+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.946+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-07-15T16:58:45.946+01:00 TRACE 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]

2023-07-15T16:58:45.951+01:00 DEBUG 21592 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

My build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.1.1'
```

Im sending the Bearer correctly and validated it with the DB.
All other endpoints/controllers with authorities work fine, register, delete etc... this one doesnt even go in the controller.

I expect this endpoint to be allowed to execute.

Comment: read how spring boot handles errors https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling then read your logs  `Securing GET /error?role=PLUS` your request is failing, so spring redirects you to `/error` and you havn't cleared the error endpoint så you get an access denied. Also, using JWTs as sessions is very insecure, there is a reason as to why spring does not supply a JWT-as-session filter. Your application is vulnerable to Cross-site-scripting attacks, DDoS attacks and you cant logout the user. Using JWTs as sessions is very insecue

Comment: whatever tutorial you are following is giving you bad advice, and this is why you should not build custom security solutions.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/client/createUser").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/client/home").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .csrf(csrf -> {
                    csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/client/createUser", "/api/client/home");
                })
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Firstly I had a v"i" instead of a v1 in the controller so I would never get the request passed, and then it was a matter of CSRF config.

**CSRF Token Generation:** Spring Security enables CSRF protection by default. Even if an endpoint is configured with permitAll(), CSRF protection might still be applied. To properly exclude an endpoint from CSRF protection, you might need to explicitly disable it for that endpoint. You can do this by chaining .and().csrf().disable() for the specific endpoint configuration.

**SOLVED: By adding the disabling CSRF config to the securityConfig and by fixing my endpoints url.**

Comment: Yes I did change to oauth2 too.